# Refresh list items (not update) using PowerShell script

Tags: 2013, list, powershell, updatelistitems

In SharePoint 2013 **List A**, I want to refresh value of **column A** of all items, but I don't want to make new item version when I do refreshing/update.
Column A is calculated column and it is calculating difference in time between Now() and some other date column. So it would display correct value only if user manually edit item.

I found PowerShell script that updates column A, but it will leave new item version, any chance to suggest me how can I modify it so Items won't be updated?

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://Server/ListLocation
$list = $web.Lists["ListA"]

foreach ($item in $list.Items)
{
  $item.Update();
}
```

Comment: SPOnline added a SystemUpdate.. Are you the Formulas only for display? Or does its value trigger other Formulas or Workflows?

Comment: That column A will later be used for additional calculations.

Comment: Then all Front-End only solutions do not apply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://Server/ListLocation
$list = $web.Lists["ListA"]

foreach ($item in $list.Items)
{
  $item.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
}
```

Reference - [UpdateOverwriteVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.updateoverwriteversion.aspx)

You can also use:

`item.SystemUpdate();`

difference -

UpdateOverwriteVersion() - updates the list item without creating a new version, but the `Modified` and `Modified By` fields are also updated.

SystemUpdate() - updates the list item without creating a new version,also the fields `Modified` and `Modified By` are **not** updated.